# How do I create a custom dictionary in OpenOffice?

Tags: software

Writing fantasy and sci-fi, I grow a sizeable specialised vocabulary per story (names, locations, fantastical things, etc.) I grow tired of the autocorrect grumbling at this vocabulary, and would much rather have it poke me when I misspell those words.

At the same time, I do not want to pollute the standard dictionary with made-up words. I would be most comfortable with a dedicated dictionary per novel. Is there an easy way to do it in OpenOffice?

Comment: Add to dictionary?

Comment: @DoubleU Add to dictionary adds the word to the standard dictionary. This is something I specifically don't want to do: I don't need a whole lot of made-up words getting into the dictionary I also use for academic writing, nor the made-up words of one novel mixing into the made-up words of another novel.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question seems to be about technology, not actual writing.

Comment: @DoubleU We have plenty of questions on Writing.SE regarding the tools people use to write, this seems a perfectly acceptable question in a similar vein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the first word needing to be added to your new custom dictionary, once it's been highlighted by the spellchecker running in the standard dictionary for your language of choice, right click on it, choose Add, and in the pulldown choose the custom user dictionary you wish to use - this user dictionary sits atop the default standard dictionary - you can create multiple user dictionaries and choose per project if that will suit your needs.

There's a *great* community support forum for OpenOffice, and there are a fair number of posts & replies around user custom dictionary issues in specific - I include a link herein ***not*** as a proposed answer, but in order that OP have a starting point for examining the OOO fora.

[https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=93765&p=446100&hilit=add+user+dictionary#p446100](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=93765&p=446100&hilit=add%20user%20dictionary#p446100)

Hope this helps some.